# Loop a program in try/catch statments

Tags: java

I have a program that in the first instance tells the user their options and accepts the user input corresponding to the option they preffer. I have exception handling for this but if there is an exception how do i get the program to keep looping until a valid input is accepted?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Application 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            int option;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to Toys Rental Ltd! \n\nChoose an option: "
                    + "\n-Rent a toy (enter 1) "
                    + "\n-Return a toy (enter 2) "
                    + "\n-Add a new member of a toy (enter 3) "
                    + "\n-Update member details (enter 4) "
                    + "\n-Update toy details (enter 5) "
                    + "\n-Print a member and toy list (enter 6) "
                    + "\n-Print a member and rental statment (enter 7) "
                    + "\n Or for help please enter 0");

            option = input.nextInt();

            if(option 

        }

        catch (InputMismatchException iie)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you just use `if statement`? instead of a try catch statement,  validating the input first before processing would be ideal, instead of letting the exception to be catched

Comment: try wrapping the try catch in a while loop

Comment: Put the try/catch inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, put in a loop.

```
    import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Application 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean retry=true;
    while (retry){
          try
          {

                int option;
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Welcome to Toys Rental Ltd! \n\nChoose an option: "
                + "\n-Rent a toy (enter 1) "
                + "\n-Return a toy (enter 2) "
                + "\n-Add a new member of a toy (enter 3) "
                + "\n-Update member details (enter 4) "
                + "\n-Update toy details (enter 5) "
                + "\n-Print a member and toy list (enter 6) "
                + "\n-Print a member and rental statment (enter 7) "
                + "\n Or for help please enter 0");

                option = input.nextInt();

                retry=false;
         }

         catch (InputMismatchException iie)
         {
             System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again");
              retry=true;
         }           
    }


}
```

Comment: should you put `retry = false` at the end of your `try` block?

Comment: Good catch, when the Exception is thrown, the try block does break, so when there is an Exception, `retry=false` would not superfluously run. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Just add while loop, where you set the "end" boolean to true when you are sure, the input is right or set the "end" boolean to the false, when the exception is caught.

Howevever in this example, exception is not good way to handle it, simple "if (good_input)" is good enough.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean end = false;
    while (end == false) {
        try {
            int option;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to Toys Rental Ltd! \n\nChoose an option: "
                    + "\n-Rent a toy (enter 1) "
                    + "\n-Return a toy (enter 2) "
                    + "\n-Add a new member of a toy (enter 3) "
                    + "\n-Update member details (enter 4) "
                    + "\n-Update toy details (enter 5) "
                    + "\n-Print a member and toy list (enter 6) "
                    + "\n-Print a member and rental statment (enter 7) "
                    + "\n Or for help please enter 0");

            option = input.nextInt();

            if (option == 1) {
                //.....
            }
            //.....
            end = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException iie) {
            end = false;
            System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the logic that asks for and accepts input into a method other than `main`, and call that method after you print the error message, or do what peeskillet said in the comments.

Comment: That's not a loop, unless you're suggesting a recursive solution, which doesn't really fit the problem.

Comment: "Loop" seemed to me to be used in a less than strictly syntactic sense here, though I could've been wrong on that interpretation if this was a homework assignment. Calling a secondary method keeps the program "looping" from a user perspective...you're right, though, about recursion not being the greatest solution.